# Non parametric analysis

Tags: r, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

The my dataset is not normal distributed. In order to apply a non parametric analysis, exist only the Kruskal Wallis test or others?
I need to find a test similar to ANOVA to apply a dataset not normal distributed.
Thanks so much.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this test? Difference of means?

Comment: @ilanman I need to see the difference of means (similar the ANOVA). In my case I didn't use the ANOVA analysis because the may dataset is not normale distribuite.

Comment: In my experience the Mann Whitney test works well with non-normal data. It's very powerful (compared to t test) for large samples and requires no assumption on the distribution of the data.

Comment: @ilanman is possible do you write my the script?

Comment: I won't do your work for you but I am happy to help steer you in the right direction. What does your data look like?

Comment: @ilanman I choose the Kruskal Wallis test because is same test of the ANOVA analysis but for the non-parametric analysis.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're looking for. Can you explain the structure of your data? Maybe post in your question some output

Answer (score 1):

You can perform ANOVA using ranks of your variable instead of variable itself. 
This will lead to the same results with Kruskal-Wallis test.