# Testing ranks rather than actual numbers with parameteric tests

Tags: statistical-significance, ranks

An answer on this page [Non parametric analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159895/non-parametric-analysis)  states:

> "You can perform ANOVA using ranks of your variable instead of
>   variable itself. This will lead to the same results with
>   Kruskal-Wallis test."

Suppose I have following vector and I convert it to ranks as follows:

```
vector:  30,45,21,11,27,26

ranks:  5 6 2 1 4 3
```

Do following tests make any sense?

```
1. Pearson correlation between ranks of 2 vectors.

2. paired t.test of ranks of 2 vectors of same length

3. unpaired t.test of ranks of 2 vectors of differing length
```

Will they be like non-parametric tests? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: The problem is all your situations have two samples but you only describe ranking a single sample. With the t-tests in 2. and 3. how are you organizing the ranking?

Comment: I was thinking of ranking them separately for all 3 tests.

Comment: I'll address that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing them out of order:

1. is called the Spearman correlation

3. I assume we're doing the equal-variance version of the test; similar comments would apply to a Welch-Satterthwaite-type test. If you rank the samples by ranking them combined together, then compute the t-statistic on those ranks, then a *permutation test* on that statistic is equivalent to a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney. It's possible to show the two are monotonically related and the permutation test equivalence follows immediately. Here's some simulated data  showing how they relate monotonically:

[image]

(each point represents a pair of samples of size 10 from normal distributions; there are thousands of samples shown, though most points are coincident with other such points)

2. If you rank the samples by ranking them combined together, then compute the paired t-statistic on those ranks, then a *permutation test* based on that statistic won't be equivalent to a Wilcoxon signed rank test, but is correlated with it. It will still be nonparametric; I haven't made any attempt to see how well it performs in practice; I expect it will have lower power at the normal. (If you have some other way of ranking, or of organizing the test, you'll need to be more specific.)

---

As to the question of ranking them separately:

3. Let the first sample have $n$ observations and the second sample have $m$ observations, drawn from a continuous distribution. The first sample will consist of the ranks $1, 2, ..., n$ and the second sample will consist of the ranks $1, 2, ..., m$, and so the test statistic will always be *exactly* the same, no matter what values the sample consist of.

For example, if the first sample has 5 values in it and the second sample has 4 values in it, all changing the sample can do is change the order of the ranks. The test statistic will always be 0.5092. If the two sample sizes are the same the test statistic will always be 0.

This wouldn't make sense as a statistic.

2. both samples will consist of the ranks $1, 2, ..., n$; the numerator of the t-test will always be $0$; different samples can change the denominator, but the t-statistic will always either be $0$ or - when both samples have their ranks in the same order - undefined (0/0).

This wouldn't make sense as a statistic.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I was initially thinking of ranking 2 vectors separately in each test, but it seems ranking them together would make more sense. For sake of completeness, what would be the significance of tests conducted with separate ranking?

Comment: I've commented on that option

Comment: Two questions: Will ranking the vectors separately work for correlation or there also combined ranking is done (in Spearman's test)? Second, can there be any advantage of t-tests (unpaired or paired) using combined ranking over usual non-parametric tests?

Comment: The correlation case is based on ranking separately. As I stated already for the unpaired case, using the t-statistic as the basis of a permutation test makes it identical to the usual nonparametric test, in that they must reject and fail to reject exactly the same cases (and I believe this is precisely the sense in which the original quote is intended). For the paired test there may well be some advantage in particular situations ... such as in the case of the original data being drawn from some distributions, but as is clear in my answer I haven't investigated this.